# Apex trigger executing only on last record of the batch during mass update

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, insert

I'm trying to create a very simple trigger that gets fired when a process builder creates a task with certain conditions like task status = 'In Progress'.

What this trigger will do is basically it'll check certain conditions on that task inserted by process builder and if it meets, trigger needs to update task.status = 'Completed' and then call a queueable interface with list of task WhatIds for an HTTP callout.
Below is the code -

```
trigger taskInsertTrigger on Task(before insert) {
    
 List<Id> oppId = new List<Id>();
     
        for(Task t : Trigger.New){     
          if(t.RecordTypeId == 'SomeId' && t.Subject == 'Some Subject' && t.OwnerId == 'SomeId' && t.Status == 'In Progress' && t.WhatId != null){
             //t.addError('Something went wrong');
              t.Status = 'Completed';
             oppId.add(t.WhatId);
             System.debug('Task Id'+t.Id);
             System.debug('Here WhatId is getting added to list from inside IF Trigger'+oppId.size());

            }
            
        }  
    
      if(oppId.size() > 0){
      system.debug('Limit Check'+Limits.getQueueableJobs());
      system.debug('Task trigger running because list has items'+oppId.size());
      Id jobID = System.enqueueJob(new hubspotLeadIntentCallout(false, oppId)); 
            
            }
  
}
```

The issue I'm facing from last 10 days is that trigger is running on every task inserted and also marking task status as complete. However, if you look in the code oppId list is only getting one whatId value when it calls the queueable. It  looks like previous Ids are getting deleted or overritten in oppId list.

Any help is very greately appreciated!

Comment: Realistically, you'll need to check your debug logs. With the modification to the code, everything appears to be in order. Also, did you check hubspotLeadIntentCallout to make sure it supports multiple records still?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox I did some testing yesterday and it looks like everything is right with the above code. The reason it wasn't working was that I was passing just 1 id to the endpoint url bcuz it was designed that way. Passing the list works fine now.
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Yeah, no problem, glad you got it sorted out.